# How to find the problems of reallocation when it is not done

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NUM 5
#define MAX_INCR 5
int main(void)
{
    char check = 'y';
    int max_number = MAX_NUM;
    double *array_input = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    double buffer = 0.0;
    int count = 0;
    array_input = malloc(5 * (sizeof(double)));
    printf("Please enter the numbers into the array: ");

    for(i = 0; i < max_number; i++)
    {
        ++count;
        scanf("%lf", &buffer);
        *(array_input + i) = buffer;


        if(count == max_number)
        {
            printf("\nDo you want to input more?(y/n) ");
            fflush(stdin);
            if((check = tolower(getchar())) == 'y')
            {

                max_number += MAX_INCR;
                //realloc(array_input, max_number);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int j  = 0; j < max_number; j++)
    {
        printf("\nThe value is: %lf", *(array_input + j));
    }


return 0;
}
```

(freeing the memory is not done to keep the code consise)
Now, the reallocation is not done in here deliberately but the output of the program is exactly what it should be.
e.g. `5.3, 4.2, 5.6. 7.4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7.8`, the program outputs these numbers as it is, like it should.

How to figure out that there's a possible error in this program?(Example: Someone is given the program but the programmer forgot the reallocation part, it may later cause problems, right?)

Comment: For any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expressions `*(p + i)` and `p[i]` are equal. The latter array-indexing syntax is less to write and easier to read and understand. I suggest you use it instead of the explicit pointer arithmetic. Besides that calling `fflush` on an input-only stream (like `stdin`) is explicitly mentioned in the C standard as *undefined behavior*. Don't do it if you want your program to be portable.

Comment: C is a language for people who know what they're doing. People who don't know what they're doing should be using C#, and frequently are :-)

Comment: That's a fairly harsh point of view from pax, albeit amusing too ;)  To put it another way, anybody worth their salt as a C programmer doesn't even need to think about memory and allocation because it's almost as natural as breathing.  It's definitely not something you could "forget" about...  Although occasionally despite a lifetime of unconscious practice, you still accidentally try to breathe at the same time as swallowing a mouthful of water.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , really?? My book mentions nothing like that but uses it instead. So, how do we clean the input buffer then?

Comment: @paxdiablo , then c should be learnt only by it's creator himself then!! Not everyone could go to that sort of concreteness, or people learn you know

Comment: The portable solution to "flush" the input buffer is to read character by character until you get a newline.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , ;what does 'undefined behaviour' have to do with portability? Isn't it undefined on every machine?

Comment: Some compilers and libraries allow `fflush(stdin)` as an extension of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with "undefined behaviour" is that you never know. In many cases, just like yours, the program apparently behaves normal, but once you change a little bit, it suddenly crashes, even though the change itself is done correctly. Such bugs often cause security holes, since hackers can exploit them to run their own code.

There are tools to find bugs like that, e.g. http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 0):

You will never know until exception occurs. That is why people do implement various of testing codes including unit testing and function testing, etc...
Those testings enhance its reliability and quality.

Codes which has security holes are the same. 
Programmers who coded could believe that the programmed code is very solid. For example, like the developers who developed remote-drive using network connection secured. However, hackers study the weakness and try many attempts to find the weakness of the system and finally it breaks. After coder finds out its weakness, programmers improve their code from the defect. This is why cyber attack is called spear (who try to attack) and shield (who try to defense).

There are no perfect code. Once it finds its bug, it is needed to improve its quality.